# git push/merge config

Tags: git

There is following output in `git remote show`

```
git remote show origin
remote origin
Fetch URL: https://user@server/path
Push  URL: https://user@server/path
HEAD branch: master
Remote branch:
  master tracked
Local branch configured for 'git pull':
  master merges with remote master
Local ref configured for 'git push':
  master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Where `Local branch configured for 'git pull':` and `Local ref configured for 'git push':` are configured?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `git config --list` to see your complete `git` configuration, which will include sections named `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.merge` and `branch.<BRANCHNAME>.remote`.  These define the upstream branch for the given local branch.  From the entry for `branch.<name>.merge` in `git-config(1)`:

> Defines, together with branch..remote, the upstream branch
>   for the given branch. It tells git fetch/git pull/git rebase which
>   branch to merge and can also affect git push (see push.default).

The `push.default` option influences what `git push` will do absent explicit references on the command line.

Comment: I have `push.default` not set(`git config --list push.default | grep push` returns nothing). Branches created with `git checkout --track` are shown in push section of `git remote show` and branches created with `git checkout -b local_name remote_name/br_name` are not shown in that section. However I can not see any difference between config. Bot branches has remote and merge parameters set and nothing else. What am I missing?